# WPF DataGrid style cells based on index

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm binding a DataTable to a WPF DataGrid (Auto generated columns on the DataGrid).

I would like to assign a different style to all cells in the first column, last column, and last row.

How can this be achieved?

**Edit**

The problem here is I don't have a data object with defined property names, and the DataTable column names aren't constant since it's dynamic with auto generated columns.

AutoGeneratingColumn event - e.DisplayIndex is always -1, is there a path to the DataTable's column and row index from here?

Converter - how can I pass in the cell's row and column indexes?

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122131/how-to-change-a-rows-style-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: can you talk with your code.. what have you tried?

Comment: Look at this article to gain some pointers http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/wpf-datagrid-style/

Comment: have added to the question, those solutions proposed are fine if you know property/column names, but in this instance I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you store your cell style and row style somewhere in XAML Resources, I suggest you to handle two events of the datagrid in your codebehind, these are:

```
int c = myDataTable.Rows.Count;
myDataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns += (s, e) =>
{
   myDataGrid.Columns[myDataGrid.Columns.Count - 1].CellStyle = this.Resources["myCellStyle"] as Style;
   myDataGrid.Columns[0].CellStyle = this.Resources["myCellStyle"] as Style;
};
myDataGrid.LoadingRow += (s, e) =>
{
   int x = e.Row.GetIndex();
   if (c - 1 == x) e.Row.Style = this.Resources["myRowStyle"] as Style;
};
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks michele - sometimes the best/only approach is some post column/row looping in code :)

Comment: Yep, probably there's a better solution, but sometimes I prefer a quicker way to get things done!