# WPF DataGrid column properties by column name

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a way to change properties of a column in a WPF datagrid by using the column name (instead of the index).
A bit like I did with a WinForm DataGridView:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Did you try this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122131/how-to-dynamically-change-a-rows-style-based-on-row-data ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the style of this column, you can change the template style of this column dynamically in the code. If you want to change the data, it's incredible

Comment: Can you please give a specific example which answers the question?

Comment: <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}" AutoGeneratingColumn="MyGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"></DataGrid>  
                                                                                                                                          
 private void MyGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, 
DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {                                                                                                          
               DataGridColumn col = e.Column;                                       }

Comment: Of course, this is the simplest way I can write it. In this event you can get the DataGridColumn, and then you can change as many properties, length width visibility styles, and so on as you like.